# integrability formula

Tags: real-analysis, integration

Please help me with this problem

Supposed that $g:[a,b] \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ is continuously differentiable and strictly increasing so that $g'(x)>0$ for every $x \in [a,b].$ If f is integrable on $[g(a),g(b)],$ then prove that $$ 1. (f\circ g )g' \text{ is integrable on } [a,b]$$ $$2. \int_a^b (f \circ g)(x)g'(x)dx=\int_{g(a)}^{g(b)} f(y) dy$$

I tried (2) by Fundamental theorem of Calculus but it needed $f$ to be continuous..

Comment: I've only seen this theorem stated when $f$ is continuous.

Comment: Did you get this problem as a text exercise, where it was made clear it should be a true statement for all integrable $f$, or was it given in some way that it should be decided whether true or not as part of the question?